# Passing variable to gnuplot via -e causes not persistent window

Tags: bash, shell, gnuplot

I want to run either persistent `gnuplot` or write output to file. This behavior should be affected by passing variable. Here is my `test.plg`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
if (exists("file")) set term png; set output "test.png";
if (!exists("name")) exit;

set title name

plot sin(x)
```

If I run script this way it is working and output is written to file `test.png`

```
gnuplot -e "name='GRAPH NAME GOES HERE'; file=''" test.plg
```

The problem is when I do not want the output as image but rather the persistent output

```
gnuplot -e "name='GRAPH NAME GOES HERE'" test.plg
```

This time gnuplot window just appears and closes immediately.

I've tried various combinations of those:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
gnuplot -e "name='GRAPH NAME GOES HERE'" test.plg

#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
gnuplot -p -e "name='GRAPH NAME GOES HERE'" test.plg

#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
gnuplot -p -e "name='GRAPH NAME GOES HERE'" test.plg

#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p
gnuplot -e "name='GRAPH NAME GOES HERE'" test.plg
```

The result of this is that the only way when `gnuplot` stays persistent is when script starts with `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p` and It is called directly with `./test.plg` (not with `gnuplot -e`) but then no variable (`name` in this example) cannot be passed.

One workaround that I've found is to not pass variables but rather grab an environmental variables. This is a bit ugly and requires following code modification:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -p

file="`echo $FILE`"
name="`echo $NAME`"

if (file ne "") set term png; set output "test.png";
if (name eq "") exit;

set title name
plot sin(x)
```

Then the script is controlled via following commands:

```
export FILE="T"
export FILE=""
export NAME="GRAPH NAME GOES HERE"
```

and called directly via `./test.plg`

Another thing that comes to my mind is first open the window which holds the graph and then somehow load the output of `gnuplot` into it. But under `ps -elf` output I cannot find the process which corresponds to open graph. Can anybody also explain this? Is this really the only one possible way?

**EDIT** based on Christoph comments:

This Opens and immediately closes window

```
gnuplot -p sine.plg
gnuplot -e '' -p sine.plg
gnuplot -p -e 'plot [-pi:pi] sin(x)'
```

This one even does not open window

```
gnuplot -e '' -p sine.plg
```

This one is working

```
gnuplot -p <sine.plg
echo 'plot [-pi:pi] sin(x)' |  gnuplot -p
```

**EDIT2**

I have defined this alias `alias gnuplot='rlwrap -N -a -c -b"\"\"\\'\''\\'\''" gnuplot'` After `unalias gnuplot` it works, but I do not know why.

Comment: You are mixing something: the shebang (`#!`) is interpreted by your operating system, not `gnuplot`. So, if you run your script with `gnuplot test.plg`, the shebang in the first line is ignored as simple comment. For me, combining persist and `-e` works fine: `gnuplot -p -e "plot sin(x)"` shows a sine-plot in a window which remains opened.

Comment: Yes, but try to save `plot sin(x)` in to file `sine.plg` and run it via: `gnuplot -p -e "name='GRAPH'" sine.plg` you will get the same issue as me.

Comment: That works fine for me as well. I could test this only on Windows with version 4.6.6 and 5.0, though. I can do more tests on Linux only this evening.

Comment: This is weird, for me it is not working. I am running gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0 on Debian 8.0 jessie

Comment: Now I could test it on Linux. Here it works for almost any version, tested with 4.6.5 (Debian, distribution package), self-compiled 4.2.6, 4.4.4, 4.6.0, 4.6.5, 5.0. All work with `gnuplot -persist -e "file='name'" sine.gp`, where `sine.gp` contains only the one line `plot sin(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined this alias `alias gnuplot='rlwrap -N -a -c -b"\"\"\\'\''\\'\''" gnuplot'` After `unalias gnuplot` it works.